# .data() not returning undefined

Tags: jquery, html

I trying to use .data to get a value out of an attribute.

HTML

```
<div class="like" data-postid="903282304865jh"> </div>
```

JS

```
$(".like").click(function(event){ 
      var postID = $(event.target).data('postid');
      console.log(postID);
});
```

I get undefined returned in my console. Whats going on here?

Comment: Does the DIV contain other elements ?

Comment: Is `event.target` what you are expecting? (I'd output that to see) ... you may need to use either `this` or `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: A simple JsFiddle works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/D4h9C/

Comment: Also make sure the object has rendered, so wrap in $(function(){...});

Comment: @mplungjan How do you click on an element before it has rendered? The `console.log` is executing, so that's not the problem.

Comment: You can attempt to attach an event handler to an object before it rendered. Then you can click all you want and nothing will happen that you coded in the event handler. He does get a console log entry, so I assume it is assigned onload or ondomready but it is still a good thing to point out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.target)`:

```
  var postID = $(this).data('postid');
```

Your code works good if there are not other elements in div.

Also consider comparing the `target.event` with `this`:

### `event.target`

The DOM element that initiated the event. [**read more**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

---

### `this`

In jQuery, the element being acted upon is often passed to the function parameter of a jQuery function as this. It can be made into a jQuery element object by using `$(this)`. [**read more**](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?42053-jQuery-%28this%29-usage)

### Example

Your code becomes:

```
$(".like").click(function(event){     
      var postID = $(this).data('postid');
      alert(postID);
});
```

As HTML example can be the following:

```
<div class="like" data-postid="903282304865jh"><i>A</i> Test</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gYP2h/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Change `event.target` to `this`. `event.target` will be the element that was clicked, so it could be any child of your div. `this` will be the element referenced by your selector:

```
$(".like").click(function(event){ 
      var postID = $(this).data('postid');
      alert(postID);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p75JX/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".like").click(function(event){ 
    var postID = this.attributes['data-postid'].nodeValue
    console.log(postID);
});
```

**or**

```
$(".like").click(function(event){ 
    var postID = $(this).data('postid')
    console.log(postID);
});
```

Comment: The first suggestion is silly when you have jquery already, the second was already posted twice

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

`var target = event.target;`

`var getData = $(target).data('user-id');`